# ASP.NET Blazor - can't bind when passing values Cascading with object

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

This is my Blazor component:

```
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer
     
<CascadingValue Value="@now" Name="Now">
  <CascadingValue Value="@color" Name="Color">
    <Count />
  </CascadingValue>
</CascadingValue>    

<input @bind="@color" @bind:event="oninput" />    

@code {
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  string color = "red";
}
```

I can dynamically change color:

[image]

Now I decided to cascade pass data using object so my component has changed:

```
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

<CascadingValue Value="@DateTimeValues" IsFixed="true">
  <Count />
</CascadingValue>
<input @bind="@DateTimeValues.Color" @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
  DateTimeValues DateTimeValues = new()
  {
    Now = DateTime.Now,
    Color = "red"
  };
}
```

but it has no effect, I can't change the color. Where is my mistake? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `IsFixed`. It is for root level cascading values and basically disable the changed "notification".

```
<CascadingValue Value="@DateTimeValues" >
    <Count />
</CascadingValue>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#root-level-cascading-values